# Trying to pass an array of query results from Django to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

As the title says, I'm trying to pass an array of MySQL query results from django to javascript.  Unfortunately, my page source shows an array of strings containing what appear to be the query results.  Here is my django code:

```py
resultFEs = []
for result in results:
    fes = FrameElements.objects.filter(frame_name=result.name)
    resultFEs.append(serializers.serialize('json', fes))
results_json = serializers.serialize('json', results)

return render_to_response('newInstance.html',{'scene_id':scene_id,'corpus_id':corpus_id,'sentence_id':sentence_id,'word':word,'word_position':word_position,'results':results_json,'resultFEs':resultFEs})
```

Here is my html:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var word = '{{word}}';
    var wordPosition = '{{word_position}}';
    var sceneId='{{scene_id}}';
    var corpusId='{{corpus_id}}';
    var sentenceId='{{sentence_id}}';
    var results ={{results|safe}};
    var resultFEs={{resultFEs|safe}};
</script>
```

And here is the resulting page source:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        var word = ' the ';
        var wordPosition = '0:0';
        var sceneId='1';
        var corpusId='1';
        var sentenceId='2';
        var results =[{"pk": 1, "model": "annotation_tool.frames", "fields": {"framenet_id": 234234, "name": "Using", "frame_type": "FRAMENET", "timestamp": null, "has_lexicalization": 1, "annotator": 19, "semiotic_status": "LITERAL"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "annotation_tool.frames", "fields": {"framenet_id": 234234, "name": "Use_computer", "frame_type": "FRAMENET", "timestamp": null, "has_lexicalization": 1, "annotator": 19, "semiotic_status": "LITERAL"}}];
        var resultFEs=['[{"pk": 1, "model": "annotation_tool.frameelements", "fields": {"fe_name": "Agent", "frame": 1, "framenet_id": null, "frame_name": "Using", "core_status": "CORE"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "annotation_tool.frameelements", "fields": {"fe_name": "Instrument", "frame": 1, "framenet_id": null, "frame_name": "Using", "core_status": "CORE"}}, {"pk": 13, "model": "annotation_tool.frameelements", "fields": {"fe_name": "Self", "frame": 1, "framenet_id": null, "frame_name": "Using", "core_status": "CORE"}}]', '[{"pk": 3, "model": "annotation_tool.frameelements", "fields": {"fe_name": "Agent", "frame": 2, "framenet_id": null, "frame_name": "Use_computer", "core_status": "CORE"}}, {"pk": 4, "model": "annotation_tool.frameelements", "fields": {"fe_name": "Computer", "frame": 2, "framenet_id": null, "frame_name": "Use_computer", "core_status": "CORE"}}, {"pk": 14, "model": "annotation_tool.frameelements", "fields": {"fe_name": "Self", "frame": 2, "framenet_id": null, "frame_name": "Use_computer", "core_status": "CORE"}}, {"pk": 19, "model": "annotation_tool.frameelements", "fields": {"fe_name": "Desk", "frame": 2, "framenet_id": null, "frame_name": "Use_computer", "core_status": "CORE"}}, {"pk": 20, "model": "annotation_tool.frameelements", "fields": {"fe_name": "Chair", "frame": 2, "framenet_id": null, "frame_name": "Use_computer", "core_status": "CORE"}}, {"pk": 21, "model": "annotation_tool.frameelements", "fields": {"fe_name": "Chair", "frame": 2, "framenet_id": null, "frame_name": "Use_computer", "core_status": "CORE"}}]'];
</script>
```

Notice how in the resulting page source, there are quotes around every element of resultFEs.  Basically, I don't want these quotes there, so that I have a two-dimensional array of json objects rather than a one-dimensional array of strings.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can safely convert the string into a JSON object using the parseJSON method:

```
var resultFEs = jQuery.parseJSON( {{resultFEs|safe}} );
```

See the parseJSON documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: Substituting in the code you provided led to resultFEs being null.  I also tried looping through the resultFEs of my original code and setting each element equal to the result of calling jQuery.parseJSON on itself, but that did not change anything, since the array, rather than the JSON object itself, is in quotes.

Comment: Scratch that!  Iterating through the array and calling parseJSON did work!  So, what you suggested is almost right.  Thanks a bunch!